# How to correctly get the type of fields in a row in GridView?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

My aim is to loop through all fields in each row in a GridView. The fields are of type `CheckBox`, `TextBox` and `DropDownList`. If one of them are found unchecked/empty/selectedIndex=0, I'll add it to `emptyControls` list.

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvProxyEntry.Rows)
{
    List<object> emptyControls = new List<object>();
    foreach (TableCell cell in gvRow.Cells)
    {
        Type controlType = cell.Controls[0].GetType();
        if (controlType == typeof(CheckBox))
        {
            CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)cell.Controls[0];
            if (chkBox.Checked == false)
            {
                emptyControls.Add(chkBox);
            }
        }
       ... 
    }
   ...
}
```

My problem is the `if-else` checking keeps failing to detect checkboxes (based on code snippet above).

I have a guess why this fails. Doing a debug, I found `controlType` variable is always of type `System.Web.UI.LiteralControl`.

How do I correctly get the correct type of all the fields without using field's ID? The reason I don't want to use the field's ID is to prevent code change in the future if new fields are being added to the row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution 1**

Apparently, I was targeting `cell.Control[0]`, which is the wrong control type in `cell.Controls`. So I added another foreach loop to loop through `cell.Controls` to get the correct control type that I wanted.

```
foreach (GridViewRow gvRow in gvProxyEntry.Rows)
{
    List<object> emptyControls = new List<object>();
    foreach (TableCell cell in gvRow.Cells)
    {
        foreach(Control c in cell.Controls)//newly added foreach loop
        {
            Type controlType = c.GetType();
            if (controlType == typeof(CheckBox))
            {
                CheckBox chkBox = (CheckBox)c;
                if (chkBox.Checked == false)
                {
                    emptyControls.Add(chkBox);
                }
            }
            ...
        }
       ... 
    }
   ...
}
```

**Solution 2**

[For LinQ users](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40755883/3526156)

Answer (score 1):

If a control is nested inside other control, you won't be able to find it easily. I believe you know the ID of the control at design time.

If so, you can use the following FindControlRecursive helper method.

### Helper Method

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
   if (root.ID == id) 
     return root;

   return root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
      .Select(c => FindControlRecursive(c, id))
      .FirstOrDefault(c => c != null);
}
```

### Usage

```
foreach (TableCell cell in gvRow.Cells)
{
   var checkBox = FindControlRecursive(cell, "CheckBox1") as CheckBox; 
   if(checkBox != null) 
   {
      // Do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I do know the ID but assuming I don't (so as to prevent code change if any new controls are being added in the future), how do I go about it?

Comment: Too many if else statement is not a good practice; it is fragile and hard to maintain in the long run. These days, you try to use function programming style as much as possible such as LINQ.

Comment: Thanks but I guess to use or not to use functional programming is still up for debate and largely depends on many factors for it to be worthwhile. Currently, I'm using foreach+if-else so that I don't have to check for IDs which are more likely to change or be added to in the future. Foreach+If-else can also be substituted with LINQ but I don't see how LINQ increases the performance or maintainability significantly. In @Damith's answer above, if there are new Control types to be added, you would still need to do code change while also having unnecessary overhead due to use of LINQ.

Answer (score 1):

Using Linq you can get all the checkboxes using one line

```
var unCheckedCheckBoxes = gvProxyEntry.Rows.OfType<TableRow>()
                      .SelectMany(row => row.Cells.OfType<TableCell>()
                      .SelectMany(cell => cell.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>())).Where(c=>!c.Checked).ToList();
```

same way you can get other control types by changing type and the where condition

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion to use LinQ but as much as possible, I want to identify what's wrong with my `if-else` check first before I go on to use another way.

Comment: you only check `cell.Controls[0]`, how about the other controls? you can use `cell.Controls.OfType<CheckBox>()` it will give you the check boxes in the cell. hope this helps

Comment: Ah, yes! That's the problem. I solved it by just adding another foreach loop to loop `cell.Controls`. Apparently, there are several other `LiteralControl` in each cell plus one `Control`. Anyway, I don't think I'll use Linq as it introduces overhead that results in sometimes slower results. If you rewrite my code by adding the foreach loop appropriately then I'll accept yours as answer. Else, I'll add my own solution with the additional foreach loop and add a link to refer to yours for the LinQ method.

Comment: @Mark Go ahead, Add your answer. If you learn something from my answer or comments, that's my pleasure